# Android notification and ringer volumes, a question

Tags: android, volume

The Android phones have a setting that allows you to force the notification volume to match the ringer volume, I can't seem to find that setting anywhere in SDK, can someone help me find out how to get and set it that specific setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) in MediaPlayer Class
http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(...)
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```